# angular-file-upload nervgh - how to change server url

Tags: angularjs, angular-file-upload

In my app `angular-file-upload` method `uploadAll()` calls `localhost:port` everytime.
I want it to change it to some other server ip `http://1233.3.3.3:1010/image/SaveFile`. How do I do this ?

I tried

```
 vm.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: "http://1233.3.3.3:1010/" + 'image/SaveFile'
 });

 vm.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
    item.url  = 'abcd/abcd';
 }
```

Nothing worked. Still localhost is my url.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
vm.uploader = new FileUploader({
        url: 'http://1233.3.3.3:1010/image/SaveFile'
});
```